# Override ForeignKey reference model defined in abstract Django model

Tags: django, inheritance, foreign-keys

I have an abstract model like this:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    TARGET_MODEL = 'TargetModel'
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    target = models.ForeignKey(TARGET_MODEL)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and I want to make the `TARGET_MODEL` be different in every subclass. For example a model `LikeForPost` that references the `Post` model from the `blog` application:

```
class LikeForPost(Like):
    TARGET_MODEL = 'blog.Post'
```

It doesn't seem to be working, as the `TARGET_MODEL` is not instantiated from the subclass. What would be the correct way to achieve this?

I know that I can redefine the whole `target` field in the `LikeForPost` class, but I hope there is a more elegant solution, that allows to override only the model name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I've found a solution based on a class method of the abstract class, which creates the proper field via the `contribute_to_class` method, and is initiated by the `class_prepared` signal.

It was inspired by the following article: [Django Model Field Injection](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/), and in some cases the [Django application import and missed class_prepared signals](http://www.petrounias.org/articles/2011/08/11/django-application-import-and-missed-class_prepared-signals/) article can be useful, but in my particular cases it wasn't relevant.

So, the solution is to define a method in the abstract class that will create the proper field:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    TARGET_MODEL = None  # will be overridden in subclass
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    @classmethod
    def on_class_prepared(cls):
        target_field = models.ForeignKey(cls.TARGET_MODEL)
        target_field.contribute_to_class(cls, 'target')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The subclass can be left untouched:

```
class LikeForPost(Like):
    TARGET_MODEL = 'blog.Post'
```

To make it work, the `on_class_prepared()` function must be called after the `LikeForPost` class is created, which can be achieved by hooking it to the Django's `class_prepared` signal. The best place to put it, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#class-prepared), is in the `AppConfig.__init__()` method. So we pick an application that should be responsible for this setup, in my case it is `blog`, and add the following code to `blog/apps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models import signals

def call_on_class_prepared(sender, **kwargs):
    """Calls the function only if it is defined in the class being prepared"""
    try:
        sender.on_class_prepared()
    except AttributeError:
        pass


class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'blog'

    def __init__(self, app_name, app_module):
        super(BlogConfig, self).__init__(app_name, app_module)
        # Connect programmatic class adjustment function to the signal
        signals.class_prepared.connect(call_on_class_prepared)
```

And to make this configuration active by default, configure it in `blog/__init__.py`:

```
default_app_config = 'blog.apps.BlogConfig'
```

---

This solution was tested in Django 1.10, and behaves identical to a normally-defined hardcoded field when running a server, tests of the model , and when preparing migrations with `manage.py makemigrations`.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://blog.jupo.org/2011/11/10/django-model-field-injection/) by [Stephen McDonald](https://github.com/stephenmcd) describes exactly the same @BartoNaz 's answer method, named as *Django Model Field Injection*, and gives some more context on **other approches drawbacks** :

> One approach is to implement as many of the model classes as possible as abstract base classes, so that users can subclass these with their own models. This approach makes sense for certain types of customisation, and it’s what I’ve done with django-forms-builder for example. Some caveats exist with this approach however. Firstly, relationship fields can’t be defined on the abstract models, so these need to be implemented in concrete models either within the same app, or by the user implementing their own subclasses. Secondly, any functionality that references your models, such as views or middleware, needs to either have configurable settings for choosing which models to use, or be reimplemented entirely by the user to make use of their custom fields.
>
> Another approach is to simply recommend that users subclass the models that the app provides using multi-table inheritance. Unfortunately this will introduce unnecessary overhead with the extra database queries required when accessing the instances of the subclasses. Best case is that this amounts to an extra query or two in a view dealing with a single instance. Worst case is that when this approach is used with a queryset in a template, an extra query is performed for each instance returned — the classic N+1 query problem.

and precises the exact goals of this *Django Model Field Injection* :

> The approach boils down to three concepts:
>
> - Dynamically adding fields to model classes
> - Ensuring Django’s model system respects the new fields
> - Getting the load ordering correct for the above to work